# How to do a row count with a specific set of Data in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that shows me total revenue grouped by fiscal year, fiscal quarter, and business type.  I need to add a final column that counts the number rows that make up the total revenue number where each row represents a single business.

Basically I need to know how many individual businesses in a particular business type contributed to the total for that time frame.  I will explain in detail below.

First here is the stored procedure that feeds the report data:

```
SELECT 
id
,assess_year
,CASE
    WHEN MONTH(date_received) IN (7,8,9) THEN 1
    WHEN MONTH(date_received) IN (10, 11, 12) THEN 2
    WHEN MONTH(date_received) IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 3
    WHEN MONTH(date_received) IN (4, 5, 6) THEN 3
    WHEN date_received is null THEN 0
    ELSE 0
END as Fiscal_Quarter
,s_gross_revenue
,CASE 
    WHEN LEFT(segment, 1) = 'A' THEN 'Accommodations' 
    WHEN segment BETWEEN 'B100' AND 'B699' THEN 'Restaurant' 
    WHEN segment BETWEEN 'B700' AND 'B999' THEN 'Retail' 
    WHEN LEFT(segment, 1) = 'C' THEN 'Attractions/Recreation' 
    WHEN LEFT(segment, 1) = 'D' THEN 'Travel Services' 
    WHEN LEFT(segment, 1) = 'E' THEN 'Rental Cars' 
    WHEN LEFT(segment, 1) = 'N' THEN 'Other' 
    ELSE 'UNDEFINED'
END as Segement
FROM mytable 
WHERE s_gross_revenue >0 AND assess_year IS NOT NULL 
    AND assess_year <> '' AND segment IS NOT NULL AND segment <>''
ORDER BY ASSESS_YEAR, FISCAL_QUARTER, SEGEMENT
```

I attached an image  [(Raw Data Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNTHZ.jpg)  to show an example of the raw data returned by the procedure.

I am doing all the grouping by year, quarter, and business type in the SSRS report.

I just need a formula or grouping to count all the rows for each business that make up the total revenue.

I also attached an image of the report [(SSRS Report Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YBUM.jpg) with the empty column at the end where the row count should go.

So in the SSRS Report image  the business type "Accommodations" for the fiscal year 2014/15  and fiscal Quarter 1 should have a row count of 4455 in the final column because there were 4455 individual businesses that were listed as accommodations that had revenue in Q1 of 2014/15.  I just don't know how to do a row count based on specific criteria in SSRS.

(Also, I know the quarters look weird in the SQL, our business year starts in July)

Comment: Is the `MONTH(date_received) IN (4,5,6)` bit supposed to return 3 or 4?

Comment: It is supposed to return a 4.  I saw it and corrected it but only after I posted the old code.  Thanks though, good catch.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and if you're using SQL Server 2008+ then you can you the [`OVER(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause to do a `COUNT(...)` while keeping your detail data.

For the business count it would look like:

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY assess_year, Fiscal_quarter, Segement)
```

Here is the fully modified query, but the above part is really the only change:

```
SELECT 
    id
    ,assess_year
    ,Fiscal_Quarter
    ,s_gross_revenue
    ,Segement
    ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY assess_year, Fiscal_quarter, Segement) BusinessCount
FROM (
        SELECT 
            id
            ,assess_year
            ,CASE
                WHEN MONTH(date_received) IN (7,8,9) THEN 1
                WHEN MONTH(date_received) IN (10, 11, 12) THEN 2
                WHEN MONTH(date_received) IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 3
                WHEN MONTH(date_received) IN (4, 5, 6) THEN 4
                WHEN date_received is null THEN 0
                ELSE 0
            END as Fiscal_Quarter
            ,s_gross_revenue
            ,CASE 
                WHEN LEFT(segment, 1) = 'A' THEN 'Accommodations' 
                WHEN segment BETWEEN 'B100' AND 'B699' THEN 'Restaurant' 
                WHEN segment BETWEEN 'B700' AND 'B999' THEN 'Retail' 
                WHEN LEFT(segment, 1) = 'C' THEN 'Attractions/Recreation' 
                WHEN LEFT(segment, 1) = 'D' THEN 'Travel Services' 
                WHEN LEFT(segment, 1) = 'E' THEN 'Rental Cars' 
                WHEN LEFT(segment, 1) = 'N' THEN 'Other' 
                ELSE 'UNDEFINED'
            END as Segement
        FROM mytable 
        WHERE s_gross_revenue > 0 
            AND ISNULL(assess_year,'') <> '' 
            AND ISNULL(segement,'') <> ''
    ) data
ORDER BY ASSESS_YEAR, FISCAL_QUARTER, SEGEMENT
```

I also made a slight syntactic change in your where clause, it's the same logic but a kind of shorthand way to do it.  Rather than check if `SEGEMENT` and `ASSESS_YEAR` are `NOT NULL AND NOT ''` in separate statements you can combine them into an `ISNULL(...,'') <> ''` if `SEGEMENT` and `ASSESS_YEAR` are text type values, otherwise you will have to use `COALESCE(...)` to accomplish the same thing. `ISNULL(...)` can be replaced with `COALESCE(...)` if preferred.

This is also entirely possible by simply using `count(<field name>)` in the id column on your SSRS report. It should give you the same results.

Comment: Excellent.  Exactly what I was looking for.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @ekim110575 Happy to help where I can.